# KK-theory for commutative $C^*$-algebras

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

The Gelfand--Naimark theorem tells us to regard noncommutative $C^*$-algebras as "noncommutative function spaces". In that spirit $K$-theory the Grothendieck group of "noncommutative vector bundles" and $K$-homology the "homotopy classes of differential operators".

I want to see what $KK(A,B)$ is from this point of view, for two $C^*$-algebras $A,B$. To make my question more concrete: Is there a geometric/topological construction of $KK(C(X),C(Y))$ for $X,Y$ two (compact) topological spaces/ differential manifolds? If such a thing exists - then what is the Kasparov pairing in this setting?

Comment: Exercise 19.9.6 of Blackadar's text K-theory for Operator algebras seems to have what you are looking for when Y is a smooth manifold.  Bruce cites the 1984 paper of Connes and Skandalis for that exercise.